# Not getting refresher-icon

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic, i'm trying to get refresher icon when user pulls the page.
Default refresher-icon is coming but I'm trying with different icon it's not coming

Thanks in advance

```
<ion-refresher refreshing-text="Loading..." refreshing-icon="ion-loading-c" on-refresh="doRefresh()">
</ion-refresher>
```

Comment: Check the version of your ionic frame work by `ionic info` and try choosing the correct version of documentation and verify your code. Let me know if still issue is there. Because for me it is working with this code

Comment: I"m using **ionic 2.0.0** even i tried `<ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="spiral"
      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>` this inside `<ion-refresher>` but its not working.. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 2):

In 2022, using Ionic 6 the new refresher code is:

```js
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content 
      pullingIcon="chevron-down-circle-outline"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing..."></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

But even in 2022 the issue persists of the icon not showing, that is rectified by adding the following to your global stylesheet:

```css
ion-refresher {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality to use font icons in `<ion-refresher>` seems to have been deprecated as described [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/). Instead Ionic offers the ability to use the `IonSpinner`, you can read more about it [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/).

So your choices are in the current version of Ionic are: `refreshing-icon="bubbles"`, `refreshing-icon="circles"`, `refreshing-icon="crescent"`,`refreshing-icon="dots"`,`refreshing-icon="lines"`,`refreshing-icon="ripple"`,`refreshing-icon="spiral"`,`refreshing-icon="android"`,`refreshing-icon="ios"`.

Comment: Even I've tried `<ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>` but its not working..thanks for replying

Comment: Then something else may wrong in your project, because it works fine for me.